# New to installing SSD

Tags: windows, ubuntu, hard-drive, ssd

First time installing SSD so I have bunch of questions
I want to have Ubuntu on HDD and Windows 10 on SSD

I only have Windows 8.1 on HDD right now. Should I install Windows 10 then migrate to SSD or migrate first then get Windows 10?

Which program to use when migrating OS safely?

Do I simply remove SSD when installing Ubuntu on HDD then put it back?

Do I need a driver for SSD?

Thanks

Comment: One question per question, please. Once you do a little research, we can help with any specific issues/questions you come across.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd treat the SSD the exact same way I would treat a HDD. Typically you need no drivers for a fresh install on a SSD. If you're *upgrading* using the *free windows 10 upgrade* then I recommend migrating, then upgrading.

When I upgraded to an SSD (and from one SSD to another), I simply restored from my backups. I use veem endpoint backup, but *any* decent backup or imaging software should work, as long as it has a feature to *resize* if your drives are not identical. You can resize before or after. Many drive brands may have their own tool for migration.

Ubuntu on its own hard drive wouldn't affect the primary OS at all, it'll just stick a bootloader on its own drive which should chainload windows as needed. I have a system which had windows preinstalled (and that's unaware of my linux system) and a second independent linux partition. There is no need to remove the SSD